# UINavigationController always responds to selector interactivePopGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my `UINavigationController` I check, if it has a property `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` before I set it like so:

```
class UINavigationControllerExtended: UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.respondsToSelector(Selector("interactivePopGestureRecognizer")) {
            self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

The property can be set to nil but the property would still exists, so I would assume `respondsToSelector` always returns true. Is it necessary to check this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` property was added in iOS 7.  It make no sense to check if it exists with `respondsToSelector`.  Just use it.

Because you are calling it with *optional chaining*, if the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` property is `nil`, then:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

will safely do nothing.